# Assignment to NSArray throws exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (even with ARC turned off)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

I am new to Objective-C. What I am trying to do is to make a Twitter client. The following code always throws an error at the line `self.timeline = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:newTimeline];` and I have no idea why it happens.

This is the interface:

```
            #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

            @interface TweetList : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource> {
                NSArray* timeline;
            }

            @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* timeline;
            - (void) setCurrentTimeline:(NSArray*) newTimeline;

            @end
```

This is the implementation:

```
            #import "TweetList.h"

            @implementation TweetList

            @synthesize timeline;

            #define TWEET_LABEL_TAG 1

            - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
                return timeline.count;
            }

            - (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
                static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"TweetContainerCell";
                UILabel* tweetLabel;
                UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
                if(cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
                    tweetLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
                    tweetLabel.tag = TWEET_LABEL_TAG;
                    tweetLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:tweetLabel];
                }
                else
                    tweetLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TWEET_LABEL_TAG];
                NSDictionary* tweet = [self.timeline objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                tweetLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
                return cell;
            }

            - (id) init {
                self = [super init];
                if(self != nil)
                    self.timeline = [[NSArray alloc] init];
                return self;
            }

            - (void) dealloc {
                self.timeline = nil;
            }

            - (void) setCurrentTimeline:(NSArray*) newTimeline {
                @try {
                    self.timeline = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:newTimeline];
                }
                @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
                }
            }

            @end
```

I researched this issue a bit. One of the solutions I found was to turn ARC off. I tried that but the result is still the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the code that calls `setCurrentTimeline`:

```
                NSError* jsonError;
                self.timeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];
                if(jsonError == nil) {
                    self.output = [[NSString alloc] init];
                    TweetList* tweetList = [[TweetList alloc] init];
                    [tweetList setCurrentTimeline:self.timeline];
                    UIView* wrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
                    [self.view addSubview:wrapperView];
                    [wrapperView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                    UITableView* tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:wrapperView.frame];
                    tableView.dataSource = tweetList;
                    [wrapperView addSubview:tableView];
                }
                else
                    self.output = [jsonError localizedDescription];
```

Comment: Where are you calling `setCurrentTimeline` from?  It appears that `newTimeline` is nil at this call.

Comment: I have edited the description to add the part of code that calls `setCurrentTimeline`.

Comment: self.timeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];  Put in a log statement or breakpoint after this.  Is `self.timeline` nil or a valid array?

Comment: Most likely newTimeline is somehow bogus.  Have you tried NSLogging it?

Comment: "One of the solutions I found was to turn ARC off." This is seldom the correct answer to any problem. It is incredibly unlikely to be the solution to EXC_BAD_ACCESS (ARC's primary benefit is that it greatly reduces the kinds of mistakes that lead to that exception).

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I am rewriting this answer based on the discussion in comments.

You are making the timeline array accessible as a property in your class's header.
Because of this, you do not need to implement a custom setter for your array. Therefore, you can remove your `setCurrentTimeline` method entirely.
Change the interface to:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface TweetList : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource>{
     NSArray* timeline;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* timeline;  //assumes ARC

 @end
```

Then, when you need to set a new timeline array you can set it using dot notation instead of calling your old `setCurrentTimeline` method:

```
tweetlist.timeline = self.timeline;
```

Comment: Accessing the ivars directly in init method is generally recommended. But using the property accessor instead will normally not cause an exception.

Comment: According to the declaration he posted, `setCurrentTimeline:` is not his property setter, so he actually dodged that bullet.

Comment: Wait ... I tried removing both `self.`s after Nick Galasso updated his comment and now the variable is getting set. But the error EXC_BAD_ACCESS still shows up and it's some other part of the application that's throwing it.

Comment: You're right @Chuck, i read that too quickly and assumed it was a custom setter. I'll update my answer in a bit

Comment: `timeline` is a declared property, therefore `setTimeline` **is** a custom setter (whether explicitly declared or not). - (I did not downvote your answer, but the first version was wrong.)